# doctest in abstract class

Tags: python, abstract-class, doctest

I included a doctest in a method in an abstract class. The derived classes do not implement the method. When I do `pytest --doctest-modules mymodule.py` my test fails.

Would there be a way to tell doctest that it should test in the derived classes rather than the abstract class?

(For now, I have moved the doctest to the docstring of one of the derived classes, so that is a workaround)

*Update:*

Example with `abstract.py`

```
class MyClass():
    def add(self, value):
        """
        >>> adder = MyClass()
        >>> isinstance(adder.add(3), int)
        True
        """
        return self.value() + value
    def value(self):
        raise NotImplementedError
```

and `derived.py`

```
import abstract 
class MyClass(abstract.MyClass):
    def value(self):
        return 2
```

Here `help(derived.MyClass.add)` will show a docstring example that can actually be executed (in the derived class):

```
Help on method add in module abstract:

add(self, value) unbound derived.MyClass method
    >>> adder = MyClass()
    >>> isinstance(adder.add(3), int)
    True
```

Comment: Show us the doctest. Are you doing something silly like `x = Abstract()` and trying to run tests on `x` when `Abstract()` won't work?

Comment: I am doing what you are calling "silly". The classes are called the same in the abstract and the derived class, so from a `help(derived.MyClass)` point of view the docstring example looks ok (I would say). I have added an example.