# Suppressing doctest in abstract or Protocol classes

Tags: python, abstract-class, doctest, error-suppression

I am looking to use doctest formatted examples for an abstract (`ABC`) or `Protocol` class without having doctest fail because the methods of the class are not implemented.

The docstring and example is supposed to reflect the general use case of multiple implementations of the abstract class and I would like to keep the doctest format for consistency.

Any idea for suppressing the doctest for a single docstring or for all abstract or `Protocol` classes is appreciated. I know I could also write is as a [Sphinx code block](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/1.4.9/markup/code.html) but it wouldn't be as human readable in the code in my opinion.

Example:

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class MyABC(ABC):
    """My docstring.

    Here is a recommended use case for this item:

    Examples:
        >>> a = MyABC()
        >>> a.do_something()
        'some expected behaviour'
    """
    
    @abstractmethod
    def do_something(self):
        pass


class MyClass(MyABC):
    def do_something(self):
        return 'some expected behaviour'
```

N.B. I am aware that [this ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42631762/doctest-in-abstract-class) is kinda duplicate but I don't think the example was pertinent, nor has it been answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your doc test has to do the same thing a user would be expected to do: define a subclass that implements `do_something` and instantiate *that* class.

```
class MyABC(ABC):
    """My docstring.

    Here is a recommended use case for this item:

    Examples:
        >>> class Foo(MyABC):
        ...   def do_something(self):
        ...       return 'some expected behaviour'
        ...
        >>> a = Foo()
        >>> a.do_something()
        'some expected behaviour'
    """

    @abstractmethod
    def do_something(self):
        pass
```

Comment: Thank you, that is probably indeed the proper way. I am still waiting to see if anyone finds a more direct solution to what I wanted to do (some people might have a more legit use case)

Comment: Use case for what? There's no reason to demonstrate instantiating an abstract base class; the whole *point* is that you can't instantiate it directly. You are trying to demonstrate something that "can't" be done. (It's fairly easy to circumvent the machinery that prevents instantiation of ABCs, but that's not something you want to demonstrate in the documentation.)

Comment: I will take your word for it then. I thought there might be something else to try out than instantiating from the class or such.